# OpenGl transform feedback : getBufferSubData as GLubytes instead of GLfloats

Tags: c, opengl, gpgpu

I'm using the transform feedback mechanism to perform some GPGPU computation involving data fetched from, and saved to a file.

While profiling the app, I found out that casting the array of floats fed back by openGl to an array of unsigned char takes up to 10ms (the app works on big chunks of data).

The data fed back fits in an unsigned char (all values are integers between 0 and 255) but apparently the transform feedback returns the values as the type used in the shader (which only may be int, float or bool).

As this app needs to run as fast as possible, I wonder if there is a way to tell OpenGl to feed back the values as GLubyte instead of GLfloats, and skip the for loop casting all the values one by one?

Comment: let it return int and just assume they are all positive?

Comment: Just re-read my post and saw that I wrote GLuint instead of GLubyte... Sorry, my mistake! 

I need some GLubytes from the transform feedback. Right now I have to loop on my array, which contains around a hundred million values, and cast each value one by one, then store the new value in a new array.

I'd like to get rid of that, as it takes quite a while, by fetching GLubytes.

Comment: could you use the output directly without doing the cast?

Comment: GLfloats are typically 4 bytes wide whilst GLubytes are 1 byte wide, so no.

Comment: let me rephrase: why does the returned data need to be in 1 byte?

Comment: It's a RGB24 -> NV 12 colorspace converter working on very large images. The RGB24->NV12 conversion is just the second step in our process, we need the NV12 data in the form of uint8_t to be encoded on the fly by a hardware encoder.

Comment: It seems strange that you are using transform feedback for this. I think the more natural way would be to write to a texture (which can obviously be one byte per channel).

Comment: The size of the data exceeds the maximum size of textures on our target. We can't use textures.

Comment: Ah - OK. How many values do you write per shader invocation? Could you pack several values into a 32-bit integer?